# flask multithread app shutdown

Tags: multithreading, flask, shutdown

I have launched my flask app with the app.run('threaded=True') parameter, and I am using the recommended server shutdown routine in the flask documentation:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/

==

```
from flask import request

def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

==

When 'threaded=False' in app.run(...), the server shuts down immediately, but when threaded=True, it pauses for about 15 seconds and then shuts down.

QUESTION:

Is there something I can do inside the `shutdown_server()` function to get it to shutdown immediately?